# RabbitMQ on PCF, connect through external application?

Tags: cloud-foundry

We have a PCF 1.1 deployment, we are developing some micro-service under. We are looking to implement a pub-sub pattern using RabbitMQ as service broker. However, the publisher being an external application with the consumer being a PCF tenant app. I know you can read the enviornment variable in PCF tenant app to connect, but how to connect to the RabbitMQ from the external application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to extend `org.springframework.cloud.config.java.AbstractCloudConfig` class and create connection factory for RabbitMQ in same class. For Example,

```
@Bean
public RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate(){
   return new RabbitTemplate(connectionFactory().rabbitConnectionFactory());
}
```